# Called function as an argument type

Tags: typescript

Let's say i have a function

```
const foo = (str: string) => str + "foo"
```

And i want to have another function to only accept call of this function with proper arguments.
Some pseudocode if it's not clear what i want:

```
const bar = (fooStr: foo(string)) => fooStr + "bar"
bar(foo("typical string")) //okay
bar("jfifem") //error
bar("typical stringfoo") //error
```

ReturnType gives me string, but i don't want any string, i need specifically only ones that are returned by 'foo' function, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a use case for [branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal), which is a way to pretend at compile time that you have a special type of `string` which is different from other `string` values... but of course at runtime there's just a `string`:

```
type FooStr = string & { __fooStr: true };
```

Here `FooStr` is both a `string` and *supposedly* an object with a `__fooStr` property.  We have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convert a `string` to a `FooStr`, since it's basically a useful lie that we're telling the compiler:

```
const foo = (str: string) => (str + "foo") as FooStr;
```

Now `foo()` takes a `string` and returns a `FooStr`.  So we can make `bar()` take a `FooStr` and return a `string`:

```
const bar = (fooStr: FooStr) => fooStr + "bar";
```

That gives you the behavior you're looking for:

```
bar(foo("typical string")); //okay
bar("jfifem"); //error
bar("typical stringfoo"); //error
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAysATlAvFAzqglgOwHMoAyKAbygH0qAzBZFALilQFdoBfAbgFgAoAQGM4+HFHpwMUABQ5m2PEQCUGAHyz5UANRQARJL2qAhllgNUfQfxFjgUAEbG0mGZMYt4SVKvQb3qDr6Tih6VgIhbggyeqBguELGADaKKASERsrcUAD0OXAA1sYgEc4xAFa0uLQQALZG2XkQKChwKKUoMXEJyanphlm5Oc2t7fxAA)

---

UPDATE: you could discourage others from making `FooStr` instances by making it have a private property, as in:

```
declare class PrivateFooStr {
  private __fooStr: true;
  private constructor();
}
type FooStr = string & PrivateFooStr;
```

But since it's easy to get a `FooStr` is with a type assertion, I'm not sure if it's worth it to do that.  You'll probably just want some documentation that says `FooStr` is only meant to be a string returned from `foo()`, and that users shouldn't try to violate that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but just out of curiosity, is there way to make only foo function be able to return fooStr type? Something like private. Not a big issue if not, since you can make comment in type something like that: "Only foo should return this type", but would be cool if this was implemented.

Comment: You can't stop someone else from using a type assertion like `const evilValue = "bwahahaha" as FooStr`, so if that's what you mean, then no, you can't do this.  Practically speaking you can make `FooStr` have private or inaccessible properties so that the only way someone can feasibly get one without using a type assertion is to call `foo()`.  (e.g., `declare class PrivateFooStr {  private __fooStr: true;  private constructor(); } type FooStr = string & PrivateFooStr;`)   But since type assertions are very easy to do, it's probably not worth doing that.